# Send data from Google Compute Engine to Google Pub/Sub using Ansible

Tags: ansible, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to send data from Google vm instance to Google Pub/Sub using Ansible.

Ansible playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Write into log file
    local_action:
      shell echo "Hello" >> /etc/ansible/log.txt

  - name: Send message through pubsub
    shell: python pub.py project-344421 topic_test
    args:
      chdir: /home/pubsub
```

Error

```
    "msg": "non-zero return code", 
    "rc": 1, 
    "start": "2020-04-14 18:20:00.723265", 
    "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"pub.py\", line 22, in <module>\n    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1\nImportError: No module named google.cloud", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Traceback (most recent call last):", 
        "  File \"pub.py\", line 22, in <module>", 
        "    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1", 
        "ImportError: No module named google.cloud"
    ], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
```

Manually, the script `pub.py` runs properly with `python pub.py project-344421 topic_test`

Output

```
der_topic
Published message Hello
 now has message ID 874436722336138
Published 1 message(s).
```

The modules google.cloud, google-cloud-pubsub and google-auth are installed

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-pubsub
pip install --upgrade google-auth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the `python` executable used by Ansible is different that the one you're using at the command line.

Use the following command to figure out the path to your executable where it works...

```sh
$ which python
```

...then copy/paste the executable's path into your `shell` command.

```yaml
  - name: Send message through pubsub
    shell: /<FULL>/<PATH>/python pub.py project-344421 topic_test
    args:
      chdir: /home/pubsub
```

If this does not work, then you could also try checking your `PYTHONPATH` env var to see if it is the same in both your terminal and Ansible contexts.

Comment: Thank you! The executable path is different from the module location path. So I worked with virtualenv and it's ok now.

Comment: Glad to hear! It's amazing how many Python bugs end up being environmental